# Opening python file from terminal

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I am going through "Learn Python the Hardway" on a macbook pro. The code to follow along with is written in python 2 but my machine defaults to 3 so I thought no problem I will just run commands in the terminal to do open in python2.7. This was working fine until today when I tried to write a bash script to do the same thing and now the commands I was running don't work at all.

```
open -a "python2.7" ex3.py
```

When I run this I get back
"Unable to find application named 'python2.7'"

When I run the following:
    python2.7
It jumps into python mode.

Appreciate any help with this

Comment: Have you tried simply running `python2.7 ex3.py`?

Comment: Very embarrassing. This works great. I wonder why this didn't work yesterday hence why I started on a bash script. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like `python2.7` is in the `$PATH` variable of your terminal shell, but not in the `$PATH` variable of `bash`. Have you tried using the absolute path to `python2.7` in your script?

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also, it would be better to avoid Python 2 at this stage and start learning Python 3. You can learn Python 2 later if you need to read or work on legacy code. That way you'll avoid picking up bad habits that you'll need to un-learn. Learning Python 2 as a precursor to Python 3 is a bit like learning Shakespearean English as a precursor to learning modern English.

Comment: Can you recommend a similar rote learning method to get me into the swing of python 3? Thanks

Comment: The page in my previous comment links to several good tutorials. It's hard for me to personally recommend a beginner's tutorial because it's a long time since I was a beginner. ;)